# Refresh Django wizard form after browser's back button

Tags: django, django-formwizard, django-formtools

I am using [SessionWizardView](https://django-formtools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/wizard.html#formtools.wizard.views.SessionWizardView) from `django-formtools` project.
I've noticed that after successfully passing all form checks and executing `done()` function, which redirects to completely different view, user can still hit browser `Back` button and re-fill form again.
Isn't there any way to prevent that? I would assume that it would be some kind of session cleaning mechanism. But I cannot find any in documentation.

Answer (score 0):

After some playing around I've found that it can be achieved in two lines:

```
def done(self, form_list, form_dict, **kwargs):
    #regular form processing
    self.instance_dict = None
    self.storage.reset()
```

Now, after pressing `Back` button and submitting form it fails because no data exists and resets to first screen.